# Why sometimes Task is significantly slower than Thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I'm making a WPF application using MVVM pattern. I found sometimes Task is significantly slower than Thread. For example, in a test ViewModel:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    new Thread(() =>
        {
            Debug.Print(string.Format("Elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        }).Start();
}
```

The output usually is `Elapsed: 0`. It cost 0 millisecond. But if I replace `Thread` with `Task`. It could cost 5000~15000 milliseconds.

I tried to reproduce this in another WPF project, but failed.

My system configurations:

- Visual Studio 2010 SP1
- .NET Framework 4.0
- Windows 7 64bit.
- 4GB RAM
- AMD Phenom II 635 (4 core, 2.9 GHz)

Any ideas? Thanks.

(Sorry, I can't upload the project that has this issue)

Comment: Do you use `Task`s in the problematic project extensively?

Comment: @svick: Yes, I use a lot of Tasks in other ViewModels.

Comment: How many tasks are you running in parallel?

Comment: @Steven: I'm not sure, but I guess there could be 5~50 Tasks running simultaneously.

Comment: This is not a serious or useful way to measure speed(s).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, `Task` doesn't create a new thread, but enqueues on the thread pool. That means when all of the thread pool threads are busy, the task might wait (in extreme cases infinitely long), until it actually starts executing.

The thread pool tries to determine the optimal number of threads and it creates at least one thread per core. You can use the [`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads.aspx) to raise the minimal number of threads used, but be careful with this, it may decrease the performance.

Another option would be to create your own [`TaskScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) that uses threads exactly the way you want.

Comment: Thanks, I used `ThreadPool.SetMinThreads()` to raise the minimum number of worker threads to 100, now the UI is much more responsive!

Comment: @caveman, don't forget that if you have 100 tasks, doing them on 100 threads is *not* the fastest way. And you shouldn't probably use thread pool for tasks that are important for UI responsiveness.

Comment: @user593358 Running a windows console app in debug I call: ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out workerThread, out completionPortThreads); and get 32767 and 1000 respectively on Windows 10.  It seems you lowered the total number of worker threads?